# After I click login, the page just reloads and I’m back to the login pop up. Im using Nodejs - Auth0 - Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, auth0

I have a Node.js Express application and everything works wonderful locally. After deploying the app to Heroku the app runs, but users cannot successfully login. After I click login, the page just reloads and I’m back to the login pop up. 
Any ideas where I’m going wrong?

```
router.get('/login', passport.authenticate('auth0', {
    scope: 'openid email profile'
}), function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});

// Perform the final stage of authentication and redirect to previously requested URL or '/user'
router.get('/callback', function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('auth0', function (err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
        req.logIn(user, function (err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            const returnTo = req.session.returnTo;
            delete req.session.returnTo;
            res.redirect(returnTo || '/');
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: Any errors in the dev console of the browser and/or Auth0 logs in the dashboard?

Comment: @MathiasConradt thanks for the concern but i already solved the problem i just added this line " app.set('trust proxy', 1); " in the app.js file